# Alarm System - Detect 2.5V or 5V

Tags: gpio

I'm a newbee in raspberry and would like to add a raspberry on my home system alarm.

I have 4 zones, and checked the voltage on the four cables:
2.5V when nothing is detected and 5V when motion is detected.
How could I connect that cables to the GPIO and see the voltage difference on my Rpi.

Once done, I'd like to send email when alarm is detected.

Comment: I imagine the easiest way would be to throw in a relay that had a 5V switching voltage.  The 2.5V wouldn't be enough to trigger it, so your GPIO pin would read low, then when triggered the 5V would be high enough to trip it and would read as high.  SainSmart makes a 4 relay breakout board that is fairly easy to use.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you. When I switch to 2 other pins, the voltage changes between 0 and 2.7V. Would it be easier to detect it ?

Comment: Don't count on the sain smart and similar boards not to actuate at a lower voltage - it's not the relay coil you are driving, but an optoisolator.

Comment: With those pins you should be able to forgo the relay board entirely and just connect them directly to the Pi.  It looks like below .8 is low, and above 1.3 is high.

Comment: Unless you know what circuitry is at the other end, connecting to the Pi risks damaging the GPIO. Certainly 5V could do so. If you are adventuresome you could attempt to characterise the source by connecting different resistor values and measuring the voltage. I would definitely use some protection (series resistor, voltage clamps).

Comment: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/548/5538